# Sending message (object) alongside 404 status code (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nuxt.js

Currently learning NodeJS and Nuxt. I hope to fully understand the cycle of sending an object from the client (front-end) to the server (back-end) and then receiving a response.

For example, I wish to send a simple registration object:

```
registerInfo: {
 username: '',
 email: '',
 password: ''
}
```

This object is sent via a Vuex action:

```
async register (vuexContext, registerInfo) {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post('/register', registerInfo)
      console.log(response)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
```

The router (back-end is running in Express) receives the request and calls the appropriate function in the controller file:

```
router.post('/register', userController.register)
```

The controller file function is as follows:

```
exports.register = async (req, res) => {
  const user = new User(req.body)

  try {
    await user.save()
    res.send({ user })
  } catch (err) {
    res.sendStatus(404).send(err)
  }
}
```

I wanted to show all the steps for my question. Let us say we sent an empty object (no values were entered in the form in the front end) and the Mongoose Schema (code for that below) specifies that all fields are required.

When mongoose is about to save to the database it runs through the Schema and throws an error (ie: "Username is required") which calls the catch block code. In which, I want to send back to the client a status 404. But along that, I also want to send the error object.

However, this is what I see on the front-end console:

[image]

It doesn't include the error object (yes, in the code above I did not include it, however .send(err) does not work either). Alternatively, I can do this whole process within the try block by checking the **response** object for a **error** property. But I feel like that is hacky and not 'fool proof'. I am a junior developer so I could be entirely wrong in that regard.

Does anyone have any insight into my problem?

Thank you,

---

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    minlength: [3, 'Username must be at least 3 characters long'],
    required: [true, 'Username is required'],
    unique: [true, 'Username already exists.']
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Email is required'],
    unique: [true, 'Email already exists.']
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    minlength: [5, 'Password must be at least 5 characters long.'],
  }
})
```

Comment: Make sure your endpoint in your backend is correct: `http://localhost:3000/moments/api/register`

Comment: The whole cycle works. The ends points are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had better to return 400 (Bad Request) if the error name is `ValidationError`, and 500 for other cases.

You can use the following code:

```js
exports.register = async (req, res) => {
  const user = new User(req.body);

  try {
    await user.save();
    res.send({ user });
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.name === "ValidationError") {
      res.status(400).send(err);
    } else {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
    }
  }
};
```

Now in the client side, you can read the error response data with `err.response.data`.

```
  // REGISTER
  async register(vuexContext, registerInfo) {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post("/moments/api/register", registerInfo);
      console.log(response);
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.response) {
        /* The request was made and the server responded with a status code that falls out of the range of 2xx*/
        console.log(err.response.data);
      } else {
        console.log("Error", err.message);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

**res.sendStatus(statusCode)**

Sets the response HTTP status code to statusCode and send its string representation as the response body.

```
 res.sendStatus(200) // equivalent to res.status(200).send('OK')
 res.sendStatus(403) // equivalent to res.status(403).send('Forbidden')
 res.sendStatus(404) // equivalent to res.status(404).send('Not Found') 
 res.sendStatus(500) // equivalent to res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error')
```

In your code you're sending like this so it's skipped your error object.

So you just change like this,

`res.status(404).send(err)`

Also I have updated js,

```
exports.register = async (req, res) =>
 { 
    const user = new User(req.body)
    user.save().then(()=> res.send({ user })).catch(err => res.sendStatus(404).send(err)):


 }
```

Comment: This does not work. The error object is not returned with the 404 status code error

Comment: Now I'm getting a UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client. But I don't think its you because I changed the code back to what it was and am still getting that error now.

Comment: So now the error displays on the server's console. Nothing is sent back to the client. Says the same as above regarding the promises...

Comment: Just remove the await in save line. I just updated try with that

Answer (score 2):

**The only one reason** why you get error 404, it's because if you get some error from validation, you only `res.sendStatus(404)`.

‍ Change this `res.sendStatus(404);` to `res.status(400).send(error)`;

And now, **your code will looks like this code below**:

```js
exports.register = async (req, res) => {
  const user = new User(req.body)
  try {
    await user.save()
    res.send({ user })
  } catch (err) {
    // 400: badrequest
    res.status(400).send(err)
  }
}
```

**Updated: Register in frontend**

**You can try to use** this code first. Try to print out the response or error:

```js
register (vuexContext, formValue) {
    axios.post('/moments/api/register', formValue).then((response) => {
      console.log('Result: Succesfully to save data')
      console.log(response.data)
    }).catch((ex) => {
      console.log(`Result: Error result`)
      console.log(ex.response)
      console.log(ex.response.data)
    })
  }
```

**Updated(2): Change Form Submit**

‍ You can change your form register: `register.vue` with this code below:

```
<form v-on:submit.prevent="register(registerInfo)" method="POST" >
  <input type="text" v-model="registerInfo.username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
  <input type="email" v-model="registerInfo.email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
  <input type="password" v-model="registerInfo.password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
  <input id="register" type="submit" placeholder="Register">
</form>
```

With the form above, it's will make your form never reload when you click the submit button.

I hope it's can help you .